# Quotient of solid torus by swapping coordinates on boundary

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let $T$ be the solid 2-torus and let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $T$ generated by the relation $\{(\alpha,\beta) \sim (\beta,\alpha) \mid \alpha, \beta \in S^1\}$ on the boundary $\partial T=S^1\times S^1$. What kind of space is $T/{\sim}$?

I believe that it is $S^3$, but I can't prove it.

I posted this question already here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339019/identifying-boundary-of-solid-torus-with-itself-by-swapping-coordinates

Unfortunately, I didn't get a satisfying answer. Not sure if it's because it is harder than I thought or actually nobody cares. Maybe both :)

Comment: But the meridian of the torus is contractible in the solid torus and represents a generator for the fundamental group of the Mobius strip.

Comment: Why is your quotient space a manifold?

Comment: @TimCampion oh good question.. I don't know and I will think about it. But I'm not sure if this issue is serious enough to unaccept IJLs answer

Comment: @TimCampion The only issues would be on the diagonal. Pick a tubular neighborhood of the diagonal of $S^1 \times S^1$ such that the involution acts as negation on the fibers. Now pick a point $p$ in the diagonal. We can write down a nice half open neighborhood of $p$ by taking a small open neighborhood of $p$ in the diagonal, taking the restriction of the tubular neighborhood, and then taking the collar on that in the solid torus. By construction, the gluing can be viewed as gluing $\mathbb{R}_p \times  [0,1)$ along negation on $\mathbb{R}$, parametrized by the points in the open around p.

Comment: @TimCampion It is geometrically clear that these 2 dimensional gluings give $\mathbb{R}^2$ (it's like taping the edge of a sheet of paper to itself). So when we parametrize by the open neighborhood of $p$ in the diagonal, it becomes a $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your quotient manifold is homeomorphic to $S^3$.  I know this because it is a closed 3-manifold and its fundamental group is trivial, so I'm quoting the Poincare conjecture/Perelmann's theorem.  The fundamental group can be seen to be trivial because there is a CW-decomposition of the (2-manifold) torus with one 0-cell, three 1-cells and two 2-cells that is respected by your involution, where the 1-cells are the longitude, meridian and diagonal of the torus, and the two 2-cells are triangles.  The involution swaps the longitude and meridian while fixing the diagonal pointwise, and swaps the two 2-cells.  The quotient of the torus by the involution has one vertex, two 1-cells and one 2-cell.  The fundamental group of this space is infinite cyclic, generated by the loop around the 1-cell that started life as both the longitude and meridian of the torus.
This quotient space can be viewed as a copy of the Mobius strip, as in Taras Banakh's comment.

But now think about how the insides fits in: a CW-structure on the solid torus can be made by adding in one more 2-cell, attached around the meridian of the torus, and one 3-cell.  The extra 2-cell wraps around the generator for the fundamental group of the piece discussed in the previous paragraph.  So the fundamental group of the overall space is trivial.

Comment: Thx for this nice answer!

Answer (score 12):

I believe that your quotient space can be seen as the quotient of the $3$-sphere $S^3$ in $\mathbf C^2$ by the action of complex conjugation. The $3$-sphere $S^3$ can be identified with the join $S^1\star iS^1$ of the real circle $S^1=S^3\cap \mathbf R^2$ with the imaginary circle $iS^1=S^3\cap i\mathbf R^2$. Since complex conjugation acts trivially on $S^1$ and antipodally on $iS^1$, the quotient space is again homeomorphic to a join $S^1\star S^1$ of $2$ circles, hence is a $3$-sphere.

Comment: Thx for this nice answer!

Answer (score 9):

As yet another proof: let $M$ be the quotient of $\partial T$. Let $U$ be a small closed regular neighbourhood of $M$. Thus $U$ is a solid torus. Let $V$ be the closure of the complement of $U$. So $V$ is $T$, minus an open regular neighbourhood of its boundary. So $V$ is another solid torus.  Let $S$ be the intersection of $U$ and $V$. So $S$ is a (genus one) Heegaard surface for the three-manifold.  It is an “exercise” to show that the boundaries of the meridian disk in $U$ and $V$, respectively, meet once. Thus $S$ is the standard Heegaard splitting of the three-sphere.